# Wordpress error: Options page Setting_ not found in the allowed options list

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, errors, options

I don't really know what to do now. :/ I tryed this:

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'Setting_' );
```

And this is my strings and form setup:

```
function Setting_() {
    register_setting( 'options', 'My_plugin_header_logo' );
    register_setting( 'options', 'My_plugin_links_facebook' );
    register_setting( 'options', 'My_plugin_links_youtube' );
    register_setting( 'options', 'My_plugin_links_email' );
    register_setting( 'options', 'My_plugin_links_instagram' );
}

<form method="post" action="options.php">
  <input type="hidden"
         value="/wp-admin/options.php?page=my_plugin"
         name="_wp_http_referer">
  <p class="submit">
    <input id="submit" 
           class="button button-primary" 
           type="submit" name="submit" value="Save!">
  </p>
</form>
```

Thnaks for any help!

Answer (score 3):

Fixed!

```
 function Setting_() {
     register_setting( 'Set_my_options', 'My_plugin_header_logo' );
     register_setting( 'Set_my_options', 'My_plugin_links_facebook' );
     register_setting( 'Set_my_options', 'My_plugin_links_youtube' );
     register_setting( 'Set_my_options', 'My_plugin_links_email' );
     register_setting( 'Set_my_options', 'My_plugin_links_instagram' );
 }
    
 add_action( 'admin_init', 'Setting_' );
    
 settings_fields( 'Set_my_options' );
```